# How to access bean attribute in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl

How can we access the bean attribute in JSP?
I tried

```
<core:forEach var="header" items="${command.headerList}" >
<td><core:out value="${header.columnName}"/></td>
</core:forEach>
```

where headerList is the list of *myBean* which is having the attribute *columnName* [ getter / setter are defined in the class ]

`Expected:` it should print the value in columnName
`Actual:`  it is not printing anything at all

also how can i access the nth element in the List? i tried

```
${command.headerList[i]}
```

`Output:` nothing displayed.

## Edit:#

When i write

```
${command.headerList}
```

it displays

com.bean.MyBean@14ecb90, com.bean.MyBean@169b35, com.bean.MyBean@27d572

`This is just to let you know that the list is having something`

and when i write

```
${header}
```

inside the forEach loop it displays:

javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects$7@d9d714

`That means even header is having value, then why i am unable to print values using`

```
${header.columnName}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header` is an implicit object in JSPs that maps to request (HTTP) headers. See [the JSP spec](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/reference/api/index.html) for a full list of implicit objects.

Try referencing the bean with respect to the scope you have stored it in (e.g. `requestScope.header`). Preferably, change the name to something else.

Comment: Oh My God, now what should say. :) i changed `header` to `header1` and it worked. +10 if i could :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can we access the bean attribute in JSP?
>   I tried
>
> ```
> <core:forEach var="header" items="${command.headerList}" >
> <td><core:out value="${header.columnName}"/></td>
> </core:forEach>
> ```
>
> where headerList is the list of myBean which is having the attribute columnName [ getter / setter are defined in the class ]

Looks fine. What happens instead?

> also how can i access the nth element in the List? i tried
>
> ```
> ${command.headerList[i]}
> ```

Looks fine as long as `i` is initialized and in scope. What happens instead?

> When i write
>
> ```
> ${command.headerList}
> ```
>
> it displays
>
> ```
> com.bean.MyBean@14ecb90, com.bean.MyBean@169b35, com.bean.MyBean@27d572
> ```

It should include `[` in the front and `]` in the tail, but for the remnant it looks fine as long as you didn't override `Object#toString()` in `MyBean` class. What had you expected?

> and when i write
>
> ```
> ${header}
> ```
>
> inside the forEach loop it displays:
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects$7@d9d714
> ```

Looks fine. What had you expected?

Summarized: I don't understand your problem. Please elaborate more. Post an SSCCE. Tell about the expected input/output. Tell about the actual input/output.

**Edit** you've edited your question. Well, here are the updated answers.

> ```
> ${header.columnName}
> ```
>
> Expected: it should print the value in columnName
>   Actual: it is not printing anything at all

Then it actually didn't contain a value. To test it properly, override `Object#toString()` something like as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return "header[" + columnName + "]";
}
```

And test it using `${command.headerList}`. You can also add some `System.out` or `Logger` statement to the getter method to see if it is actually invoked and actually returned a value. Or if you understand how to use it, just run a code debugger. Every decent IDE ships with one.

Next:

> ```
> ${command.headerList[i]}
> ```
>
> Output: nothing displayed.

Then there's no means of a valid `i`. To test it properly, do the following to get the first item:

```
${command.headerList[0]}
```